# simulate an LVDS soft core IP

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, intel-fpga

I am trying to simulate the LVDS soft IP on MAX10 FPGA using modelsim-altera

it works fine with the receiver but when simulating the transmitter, I get these errors:

> Loading `fiftyfivenm.fiftyfivenm_ddio_out(behavior)`
>
> # ** Error: (vsim-3033) nofile(38): Instantiation of 'dffeas' failed. The design unit was not found.
>
> #  Time: 0 ps Iteration: 0 Instance: /top/ttx/ddio_out/loop0(0)/ddio_outa/inst File: nofile
>
> #     Searched libraries:
>
> #       C:/Users/alphatec/Desktop/test_sim/lvds_tx2/simulation/modelsim/rtl_work

Thanks for helping

Comment: A single error. verror  tells us *vsim Message # 3033: The specified design unit could not be found for instantiation. If the specified design unit does not contain a library indication then this message should be followed by a list of libraries that were searched when trying to locate a matching design unit.* The question isn't a [mcve]. Without seeing the instantiation, because it's an error it's likely an instantiation of an entity that can't be found. An unbound instantiation of a declared component is not a VHDL error. DFFEAS is an Altera/Intel primitive, found in an altera library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Modelsim-Altera, please make sure you use library 'altera'. 'dffeas' is in that library.
From command line, it should be similar to below

```
vsim -L fiftyfivenm_ver -L altera $YOUR_OWN_TESTBENCH
```

From GUI, make sure you add libraries before you start simulation.

[Add libraries to Modelsim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gupYW.png)